# Selection Tool selects random multiple points around the one aimed for

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, desktop-gis

I have a problem selecting points in ArcGis - the selection feature seems to be misbehaving, not allowing me to select point features precisely.

I've imported the XY data of households as a csv file, transformed it into a shapefile and added a boundaries layer.

I am trying to precisely select points within the boundaries, but when I try to do so manually or when I "select by location", for some reason the selection tool is really misbehaving. When I try to select points, it always selects a whole bunch of random points around the ones I actually want, making it impossible to make precise selections of the points.

I uploaded a short video that illustrates this: https://youtu.be/juw0g7cZK3A

I tried to research online but can't seem to find an answer. I suspect it is perhaps related to the fact that the coordinate system is unknown after the CSV XY import, but adding a standard one has not improved things.

Can you perhaps explain what is going on? I am using ArcMap 10.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Check your selection tolerance to see if its around 3-5 pixels and not something like 300.

Also, try opening an entirely different map that you know is projected correctly and uses different datasets and see if it works. If it does, then its probably a data issue and I would check your projection again and maybe the [precision](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/migrating-to-high-precision.htm) if it is in a geodatabase, although it doesn't really sound like a precision issue.

[image: from ESRI's help file]

from [Esri's Selection Help file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/selecting-features-interactively.htm)